# Windows Desktop Search - Force re-index / index now from command line

Tags: c#, asp.net, wds, windows-search

I'm working on a project where we're using Windows Desktop Search (WDS) to index files on a web share and then later allow the user to search via a website for documents in the share.

These documents are transferred to the share via FTP, however it would seem that either the computer never goes idle to index or at some point the indexing stops.

Is there a way from the command line or within the program itself to force this to happen without having to re-invent the wheel?

Using .NET 3.5 and C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Windows Search Code Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940344(VS.85).aspx). They seem to have several examples on how to programatically work with Windows Search. Download the samples from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowssearch. (This is for Vista and Windows 7)

If you are using Windows XP, check out the docs on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965713(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: This led me to the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266414(v=VS.85).aspx eventually which contains a method for actually re-indexing via code. Hopefully that will work thank you!